# Disable hover on link, background image hover effect causes flickering

Tags: jquery, css, hover, flicker

I'm currently working on an image with a hover effect. When you hover over the image, a link becomes visible. The image has a blur effect on hover. Problem is when you hover over the link (that becomes visible on top of the image) the image starts flickering (between blurred and not blurred).

Some code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".realisatieslink1").hide();
  $(".realisatiesafb1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".realisatieslink1").show();
  });
  $(".realisatiesafb1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".realisatieslink1").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.realisatieslink1 a {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white !important;
}
.realisatieslink1 {
  margin-top: -120px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
.editing .realisatieslink1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.realisatieslink1 p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">

  <div class="ccm-custom-style-container ccm-custom-style-slide31-83 realisatiesafb1 realisatieafb">
    <a href="http://grafomantestsite2.be/index.php/realisaties">
      <img src="http://grafomantestsite2.be/application/files/6314/4161/6181/realisatie1.png" alt="realisatie1.png" width="401" height="269" class="ccm-image-block img-responsive bID-83">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="ccm-custom-style-container ccm-custom-style-slide31-85 realisatieslink1" style="display: none;">
    <p><a href="http://grafomantestsite2.be/index.php/realisaties">BEKIJK REALISATIES</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the flickering stop?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: not hovering]

[image: Hovering]

Edit: 
I'm working in the CMS concrete5 which limits my abilities to edit the HTML. 
Just discovered that the image effect does not flicker in firefox, it does in chrome and safari.

Edit: image css:

```css
.realisatieafb {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.realisatieafb img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
    top: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.realisatieslink1 {
  margin-top: -120px;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
.realisatieslink1:hover {
    display:block;
}
.realisatieafb img{
    position:relative;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".realisatiesafb1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".realisatieslink1").show();
  });
  $(".realisatiesafb1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".realisatieslink1").hide();
  });

});
.ccm-custom-style-container.ccm-custom-style-slide31-85.realisatieslink1:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLz19way/2/

Update:
You can add a class when hover over the text, for the container:

```
  $(".realisatieslink1").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".realisatiesafb").addClass('hover');
  });
  $(".realisatieslink1").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".realisatiesafb").removeClass('hover');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives the same result, when i hover over the link 'BEKIJK REALISATIES' the image hover effect disappears, so its not blurry anymore. This results in flickering of the image blur effect.

Comment: @JacobVanAchter Try again please. I updated the answer.

Comment: @JacobVanAchter I thought the problem is with the text, but I don't see that effect. Just add the effect also for text:hover.

Comment: @JacobVanAchter Where is the css for the image?

Comment: @JacobVanAchter I don't know what is that effect, but try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LLz19way/3/ (the effect cand be a transparent din over the image). Hope this helps.

Comment: In your latest fiddle you can also see some flickering when you hover over the link. I guess it has to do with the z-index? The link is on top of the image. So when you hover over the link, you don't hover over the image, so it disables the image hover effect.

Comment: @JacobVanAchter Like I said, please share the css for the image if you want a complete solution. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. Added the css, i don't know if this is allowed, but here's the link of the project if that would be more helpful: http://grafomantestsite2.be/

Comment: @JacobVanAchter I can't do a lot of tests there, but try delete the z-index and try the code I suggested. You can also add a class for the hover efect. Maybe will be more easy to add the class when the text is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok for you, you can move `realisatieslink1` inside `realisatiesafb1`. Everything should work then.

http://jsfiddle.net/pLtc88he/

Comment: This is something i can not do, because of restrictions of the concrete5 CMS system. I'm working with an image block for the image, and a content block under the image block for the link 'BEKIJK REALISATIES'.